# Nack message and choose redeliver time

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to nack a message and tell the pubsub backend to redeliver it in X seconds?

I'm not seeking for a global retry policy as I know the subscription has exponential backoff retry option, I'm looking for a way to indicate for a single message to be redelivered in X seconds.

Comment: I've personally not heard of such a capability in GCP PubSub.  Maybe you can describe your thinking on how you would use such a capability?

Comment: same here. Since you cannot even define a priority between messages, you cannot send a message back to the queue and say "hold this for X seconds". The only thing you can prolong is the ACK deadline for each message. This is usable in the cases where you cannot process the message before it gets redelivered, so you can prolong the ACK deadline for that message.

Comment: No, you cannot. Cloud Pub/Sub is designed for messaging. Your question suggests you're trying to use it like some kind of job/task queue. If you need more fine-grained control over the individual jobs, consider acking the pubsub message and relaying the work to a system that is actually designed for letting the application control backoff/delay.

Comment: If you don't ack the message you are nacking it implicitely, what's more, if you request more time to process the message (with [modifyAckDeadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline) option) your are also forcing to re-deliver the message after this mod ack time (in secs), this might help for your purpose of redeliver after certain time. However, I think as well that it will be better you elaborate more on your use case if this doesn't help

Comment: Thanks for your comments they were really helpful

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have noted, there is no built-in way to do this in Cloud Pub/Sub for a single message. If you want a message to be redelivered in X seconds, you will need to prolong its ack deadline for X seconds and then nack it (which will then trigger redelivery).